# How to set an unattended Mac to automatically download files & photo originals from various iCloud accounts e.g Family Shared iCloud Storage?

Tags: macos, icloud, photos

I have 2TB of iCloud storage, with Family Shared Storage turned on and several accounts in use by various family members. I would like to maintain a local copy of this 2TB, and I have a spare Mac to use for the job.

My issue is that, as far as I understand, macOS will only sync iCloud (files and Photo Library etc) for the currently logged-on user.

How do I set it up to automatically log into and sync files & photos from all of our iCloud accounts (e.g. every night)?  I don’t want to have to manually rotate through changing users every time.

FYI I am comfortable with using Terminal, but not an expert Terminal user.

Answer (score 1):

You could try enabling **Fast User Switching**, then logging in to all of your family’s accounts. Fast-switching between users keeps the previous user logged in, so processes running on that account should keep running in the background (albeit with a lower priority).

1. Open **System Preferences** → **Users & Groups** → **Login Options**.
   [image: Users & Groups]
2. Click the **Padlock** to unlock Administrator-only options.
3. Finally *enable* **Show fast user switching menu as** (*Icon* or *Name* doesn’t matter).
   [image: Login Options]
4. Now click the new option that should have appeared on the right side of your macOS menu bar, and login to another user account.
   [image]
5. This should be sufficient since `cloudd` and `photolibraryd` will start automatically to sync your files and photos. However if you want to be safe, open up the **Photos** app.
6. Repeat steps 4-5 for every family member.

You should only need to repeat this procedure if you reboot your Mac (eg. after a system update).

Screenshots courtesy of [How-To Geek](https://www.howtogeek.com/339517/how-to-enable-fast-user-switching-in-macos).